# Using the Properties of Similar triangles and angle properties to find the length AC

Tags: geometry, modular-arithmetic, angle

[image]

Find the length of AC

What i tried

Since the diagram is a trapezoid, angle $DAB$ is $180-140=40$ degrees. Then using the properties of simillar triangles, angle $DAC$ is equal to angle $CAB$,thus angle $DAC=40/2=20$ degrees.

Then using the sine rule we can find length $AC$ using the formula,

$$\frac{AC}{sin140}=\frac{3}{sin20}$$

Am i correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: If that trapezoid was intended to be planar, as it undoubtedly was, it is mislabeled. No figure with those angles and edge lengths can exist in a plane. Your answer is correct based on the attributes of the figure you used. Two other answers are possible by using different attributes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see that $\angle ACB=\angle CDA$ and $\angle BAC=\angle ACD$, therefore $\triangle ABC\sim \triangle CAD$. Thus we have $$\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{DC}{AC}\Rightarrow AC^2=12\cdot 3\Rightarrow AC=6$$